# Check if a given Process is modifying an open File in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix

How Do I Check If a given Process is modifying an open file in UNIX?
Only Bash built-in and native UNIX commands are allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof` command and grab the process ID if.

```
lsof "fileName" | grep PID
```